# Почему не создаются теги в django-taggit?

Tags: python, django

В INSTALLEDS_APP добавлено 'taggit

models.py

```js
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from taggit.managers import TaggableManager


class TodoItem(models.Model):

    tags = TaggableManager(),

    PRIORITY_HIGH = 1
    PRIORITY_MEDIUM = 2
    PRIORITY_LOW = 3

    PRIORITY_CHOICES = [
        (PRIORITY_HIGH, "Высокий приоритет"),
        (PRIORITY_MEDIUM, "Средний приоритет"),
        (PRIORITY_LOW, "Низкий приоритет"),
    ]

    description = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    is_completed = models.BooleanField("выполнено", default=False)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="tasks")
    priority = models.IntegerField(
        "Приоритет", choices=PRIORITY_CHOICES, default=PRIORITY_MEDIUM
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.description.lower()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ("-created",)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("tasks:details", args=[self.pk])

    class Widget(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

Миграции применялись

```js
python manage.py makemigrations tasks
    python manage.py migrate
```

В консоли:

```html
>>> from tasks.models import TodoItem
>>> t = TodoItem.objects.get(pk=14)
>>> t.tags
(<taggit.managers.TaggableManager>,)
>>> t.tags.add('cat', 'dog')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'add'
>>>
```

Если вызвать `>>> t.tags.all()`

```
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'all'
```

```html
pip freeze

dj-database-url==0.5.0
Django==2.1.5
django-heroku==0.3.1
django-taggit==0.23.0
gunicorn==20.0.4
Pillow==7.1.2
psycopg2==2.8.5
pylibmc==1.6.1
pytz==2020.1
q==2.6
whitenoise==5.1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Уберите запятую в модели:

```
class TodoItem(models.Model):

    tags = TaggableManager(),  # тут
```

Comment: если убрать, то сервер не запускается  
 код ошибки здесь pastebin.com/Abkrf4mL